# How can I make a shader effect that looks like a lightly shaded pencil drawing?

Tags: shaders, opengl-es2, post-processing

I want to make a shader effect using OpenGL ES 2.0 that looks like this image:

[image: lightly shaded pencil drawing]

I'm not sure if this image was painted or is the result of some filter, but I want to create a shader that produces images looking similar. 
I want to know a Shader algoritm to produce this kind of output!

Comment: That is a poorly scaled and jpeg compressed drawing, there is no obvious shader effect in that image.

Comment: I agree the original question is off-topic but I think what the OP is more interested in is how a similar effect can be produced and so I've adjusted the question to highlight that rather than the (uninteresting) question about the origin of the referenced image.

Comment: @JoshPetrie Really? For all I know he could be asking for a shader to create JPEG artefacts. And your edit hasn't even rectified that.

Comment: @eBusiness He could also be trying to create a shader to output the color white. Or draw shoes. Both of those are in the image as well; I'm trying to assume good faith here and utilize the collaborative editing facilities of the site to try and *preserve* a potentially good question rather than immediately shut it down. The rest of the community is free to disagree with me (and vote down / to close as appropriate).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I can't tell if that specific image you linked was painted that way originally or not, but the resulting effect looks *similar* to an [edge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) filter.

Edge detection post-processing is often done using a [Sobel filter implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator). For example, as seen [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94817/Pixel-Shader-for-Edge-Detection-and-Cartoon-Effect) (a CPU-side implementation). The effect can be achieved in shaders as well ([here is an HLSL example](http://www.neatware.com/lbstudio/web/hlsl.html) that is trivially adaptable).

Comment: +1 Looking at a [better quality version](http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_luzh89YW5t1r48cu0o1_500.jpg), I'd say it's a combination between edge detection and hand drawing. But edge detection is the best start for this.

Answer (score 7):

To complete what Josh said, [Convolution Matrix](http://beej.us/blog/data/convolution-image-processing/) is what you want:

[Convolution in Gimp](http://gimp.open-source-solution.org/manual/plug-in-convmatrix.html)
[Another link](http://www.aishack.in/2010/08/image-convolution-examples/)

What you probably are looking for:
[Convolution Kernels in OpenGL](http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/image_filtering.php)

Comment: Your answer combined with some of the keywords from Josh Petrie's answer encompasses almost everything necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind having little bit more expensive shader (but it has same number of texture fetches as sobel filter), you can implement frei-chen edge detector.

It provides smoother image than sobel filter.

Great article with example implementation:
http://rastergrid.com/blog/2011/01/frei-chen-edge-detector/